# using hbase as key-value store, need to extract a value using java

Tags: java, hbase, key-value-coding, key-value-store

I am working on using Hbase as a Key-Value store where we have a column family with one single value. The java filter gets the row in less than a second but when trying to retrieve the value takes 15 seconds. If someone could look into it and give me pointer it would be very helpful. Here is the code :-

```
        Scan scan1 = new Scan();
        scan1.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes("column_family"), Bytes.toBytes("column_name"));
        Filter filter1 = new RowFilter(CompareFilter.CompareOp.EQUAL,
          new BinaryComparator(Bytes.toBytes("hashvalue")));
        scan1.setFilter(filter1);
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        ResultScanner scanner1 = table.getScanner(scan1);
        System.out.println(scanner1.next().getColumnLatestCell(Bytes.toBytes("column_family"), Bytes.toBytes("column_name")));            
        long endTime = System.nanoTime();
        double seconds = (double)(endTime - startTime) / 1000000000.0;
        System.out.println("Scan with row key using scan: " + seconds);            
        scanner1.close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do a scan if you know the exact value of the key, you can do a [Get](https://hbase.apache.org/0.94/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/HTableInterface.html#get(org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Get)) instead, which should be super efficient.

```
Result result = table.get(Bytes.toBytes("hashvalue"))
```

The reason why it's taking too long when you trigger `next` is because every call to `next` is an `RPC` call (a trip to `HBase`) by itself,you can use [setCaching](https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Scan.html#setCaching(int)) to get a certain number of rows in a single trip to `HBase`.